# Xlwings library for IronPython

Tags: ironpython, xlwings

Does *xlwings* work with **IronPython**? If so how could I install xlwings package in Visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is no. xlwings is built on top of pywin32 and I don't think that pywin32 runs on IronPython.

But you could use the .NET COM interop facilities instead to manipulate Excel, see [here](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Interacting_with_Excel).